# Using unicode "combining right arrow above" to generate vector command

Tags: math-mode, unicode, unicode-math

> This question originated from a confusion created by some Linux
>   systems where, for some software (editor and browser) the combining
>   unicode characters appear to apply to the right (instead of to the
>   left like the documented convention). So it could be a "localized" issue
>   (well, localized to all Linux systems). In fact this bug looks like a
>   useful feature because it allows straight conversion for the typesetter
>   commands. Still answers and notes about unicode math with accents are greatly appreciated.

The `unicode-math` [list of symbol](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) describes "combining right arrow above" (`⃗` or `⃗x`) as translated into `\vec` in Section 7.

How is one supposed to use this feature of `unicode-math`?

In this example I don't get the arrow above the `$x$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$ ⃗x$ %this line contains the unicode arrow and the x character (in case your browser doesn't show it).
\end{document}
```

(The compilation with `lualatex` and `xelatex` shows simply *x* with no arrow)

This is strange because `unicode-math` works for other things like superindexes, etc.

**EDIT:** For those having trouble seeing the unicode characters, here it is an screenshot of my editor (`gedit`), my browser shows basically the same:

[image: geditunicode]

**EDIT 2:** This is how @Jukka answer looks like in my browser:

> screenshot: [image: jukka]

**EDIT 3:** I realized that the rendering (of the text/code) is very system dependent, so if you answer this question please add a screenshot of what you see in your editor or browser. There is probable bug filed already about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/51554.

For example, so far, I find that `<arrow>x` renders the arrow over the `x` in Gedit 3.10 and Firefox 28.0 and the arrow before the `x` for TeXworks and Google Chrome. In later version of gedit 3.34, the arrow appears alone before the `x`.

Comment: Interestingly for me in firefox it is drawn on the character *before* the x.

Comment: In Firefox Linux the arrow shows above the `x`. Maybe depends on the font. This is the precise symbol http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20d7/index.htm.

Comment: Generally speaking it's best to avoid such combining characters in typeset work and let the typesetter position the vector arrow. Not least because then you will get consistent behaviour if the base is not just a single letter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, I want to rely on `unicode-math` to do that transformation for me. I am attempting on purpose to enter code in that way (through unicode), and then rely on a package to do the transformation to the typesetter for me. I am experimenting with it.

Comment: But that transformation is hard in tex as a combining character comes after the base and a tex accent command has to come before, so you would need to make every character such as `x` look ahead to see if it is followed by a combining character. which is possible but will break some things and be slow, and just telling people not to do that seems like a better option (although I don't maintain unicode-math so it isn't my decision)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know the technical intricacies but what makes me think that it is possible is that if I define `\newunicodechar ⃗{\vec}` (note the arrow character) (in a different document) it works pretty well indeed as expected. I was doing this until I saw that `unicode-math` can (in principle) do the job (better I presumed).

Comment: but if you do it that way don't you have to enter the arrow before the base so ⃗  x becomes \vec x and it all works? I can't see how you can make x ⃗  become \vec x without major surgery to the TeX macros.

Comment: Yes, it does! My editor (`gedit`) and my browser (`firefox`) nicely puts the arrow over the letter when I "type" the arrow first and then the letter. Which I guess turn it natural for the typesetter to transform the arrow into the command and then the letter as argument of the command (if I am using the right wording).

Comment: @alfC should have specified that I'm on windows now. That does suggest it's rather fragile though.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, to make it work in Tex you have to enter the arrow first but then that completely breaks its use as a unicode combining character as in the source display `$` `arrow` `x` `$` would put the arrow over the `$` even though you had set TeX up to make it `\vec` which puts the arrow over the `x`. Moral of the story: don't do that!

Comment: Note in your screenshot you have a space before the arrow, and the arrow is combining with the space (then accidentally as a result of artefacts of the font metrics and/or glitches in the handling of combining characters over space the arrow is protruding over the x but that is essentially a bug and not the intended display of a combining character. Try x<arrow>y the arrow will go over the x in the source but TeX will see x\vec y and put the arrow over y

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know if this is an accident but `<arrow>x` always looks good in terms of having the arrow over the letter. So I assumed the convention was that the "combining" character goes before the letter. (and that makes it work in the `newunicodechar` version. There is no space (in the file), the space is created visually by the editor when "combining character" is typed. "x<arrow>y" (in this editor shows the x and the arrow over "y".

Comment: ok, I can confirm that within linux the result is inconsistent, LibreOffice renders things the way @DavidCarlisle describe (independently of the font). It seems now fortuitous the way that gedit and firefox behave, could this be a sign that the convention (of pre/post) is changing. The gedit behavior is more amicable to translating into TeX.

Comment: No the convention isn't changing unicode has always specified that combining characters follow their base and this won't change, you are seeing a strange effect when you combine with a _space_ in some applications that is making the arrow appear to come over the following character.

Comment: You say  "no space in the file" but there is a space in the document you posted in the code section.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I checked, I don't know if `gedit` is doing something funny but if I count the number of backspaces to delete the whole equation line, there is no space! (even for the text copied from the browser). The first backspace deletes the `$`, then the `x`, THEN the arrow and the space (visually, at the same time), and then the last `$`. gedit and Firefox are playing tricks on me. (Fedora 20, Firefox 28, gedit 3.10, Liberation Mono font). I found this very old bug-ticket for Ubuntu https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/51554.

Comment: copy the text from your posted code `$ ⃗x$ %this` to the first text block at http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/ and hit convert you see the code points displayed as `0024 0020 20D7 0078 0024 0020 0025 0074 0068 0069 0073` so the second character is U+0020 ie a space.

Comment: Copied from my posting, Yes, I get the same, `0024 0020 20D7 0078 0024 0020 0025 0074 0068 0069 0073`. So it is `gedit` that bundles together `0020 20D7` (the space and the arrow, such that for all typing purposes the arrow behaves like a "pre"-accent). Also I now tried another editor (`TeXworks`) and works as you (and all the rest describes), it will be nice to see if other Gnome/Linux user experience the same. Also it worth remembering that in any case `unicode-math` is not working with respect to the combining character.

Comment: Firefox 42 and Gedit 3.16.1 in Linux now show a standard result (different from my original posting).

Comment: x⃗ x⃗ x⃗ x⃗ x⃗ x⃗

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Unicode, a combining mark is associated with the character that *precedes* it, so you should use `$x⃗$`(the content between dollar signs is letter `x` followed by U+20D7 COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE). And you should declare a mathematical font that contains the character.

But it still won’t work, presumably due to limitations in unicode-math, in fonts, or in the LaTeX interpreter(s) you are using. Combining marks are often poorly implemented in fonts (their metrics are wrong, causing the mark to be misplaced) and in rendering software (as we can see here: x⃗ does not look right at all).

The conclusion is that you should use methods like `\vec{x}` or, if you can choose the notations used, use bold face for vectors instead of an arrow above. Bold face is the primary notation according to the ISO 80000-2 standard and the only notation described in the US standard (ANSI/IEEE Std 260.3-1993). It is also typographically more robust.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha, you say "as we can see here ... does not look right at all". It does look right in my browser!! I'll add the screen shot in my question. For some reason my browser and my editor seem to work such that the combining character affects to the right.

Comment: I found this in the Wikipedia entry which confirms what you say "In Unicode, diacritics are always added after the main character, so it is possible to add several diacritics to the same character, although as of 2010, few applications support correct rendering of such combinations.". However my applications behave as is if the opposite where true. And, if I believe that it makes it very friendly for the typesetter to transform the combining character into commands.

Comment: To confirm, as you say, the arrow after the letter still doesn't produce the vector in the resulting PDF.

Comment: After all the confusion about the order (TeXworks works as everybody describes). Does "combining character" works in you `unicode-math` and typesetter? Mine are `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.6-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2014/dev)` `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013122811 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (rev 4627)`. `Fedora 20`.

Answer (score 16):

Like the other answer already said, in Unicode the combining characters come after the base characters. Also this is not supported by `unicode-math`.

But at least for LuaLaTeX you can add support for U+20D7 as a combining character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\mathcode"20D7="8000
\directlua{
  local func = luatexbase.new_luafunction'aftervec'
  token.set_lua('aftervec', func, 'protected')

  local nest = tex.nest
  local noad_id = node.id'noad'
  local accent_id = node.id'accent'
  local math_char_id = node.id'math_char'

  lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
    local level = nest.top
    local last = level.tail
    if not (last and last.id == noad_id) then
      tex.error'I can only put accents on simple noads.'
      return
    end
    if last.sub or last.sup then
      tex.error'If you want accents on a superscript or subscript, please use braces.'
      return
    end
    local acc = node.new(accent_id, 1)
    acc.nucleus = last.nucleus
    last.nucleus = nil
    acc.accent = node.new(math_char_id)
    acc.accent.fam, acc.accent.char = 0, 0x20D7

    level.tail = last.prev
    level.head = node.remove(level.head, last)
    node.flush_node(last)

    node.write(acc)
  end
}
\letcharcode"20D7=\aftervec
\begin{document}
$x⃗y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If you want to support all Unicode math accents, you can automate this using the symbol table from `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\directlua{
  local func = luatexbase.new_luafunction'afteracc'
  token.set_lua('afteracc', func, 'protected')

  local nest = tex.nest
  local noad_id = node.id'noad'
  local accent_id = node.id'accent'
  local math_char_id = node.id'math_char'

  lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
    local level = nest.top
    local last = level.tail
    if not (last and last.id == noad_id) then
      tex.error'I can only put accents on simple noads.'
      return
    end
    if last.sub or last.sup then
      tex.error'If you want accents on a superscript or subscript, please use braces.'
      return
    end
    local acc = node.new(accent_id, 1)
    acc.nucleus = last.nucleus
    last.nucleus = nil
    acc.accent = node.new(math_char_id)
    acc.accent.fam, acc.accent.char = 0, token.scan_int()

    level.tail = last.prev
    level.head = node.remove(level.head, last)
    node.flush_node(last)

    node.write(acc)
  end
}
\AtBeginDocument{
\begingroup
  \def\UnicodeMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifx#3\mathaccent
      \def\mytmpmacro{\afteracc#1 }%
      \global\letcharcode#1=\mytmpmacro
      \global\mathcode#1="8000
    \fi
  }
  \input{unicode-math-table}
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
$x̃ŷz̄x⃗y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to play with this now.

Comment: Would (Can) one need to do this for every accent symbol? e.g. double arrow, tilde, dot, dotdot?

Comment: @alfC See the edit. For some LuaTeX versions this can trigger [a LuaTeX bug](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2018-October/006112.html).

Comment: @Marcel Krüger: I tried your solution code in Plain LuaTeX, but there it does not work. You seem to be an expert, maybe you could look at my new question... :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524677/using-unicode-combining-right-arrow-above-to-generate-vector-command-in-plain

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Is there a way for the U+20D7 to actually call `\vec{}` over the node below it? This command is redefined in my case and does not produce the same result as using the unicode U+20D7 character in output (for instance depending on the context it might alias to `\symbf{}` instead). Please tell me if you think this should be a new question rather than an update to your answer here.

Comment: @Archange Using `\vec` itself is incompatible with this approach since the character has already been read and a variant chosen, so especially something like `\symbf` which changes the input to output mapping and therefore requires the input to be known can't be applied generally. You could of course adapt the Lua code to e.g. sometime do the equivalent of `\symbf`, but not just by changing the TeX macro. There are other approaches to get automatic `\vec` insertion, but they are based on rewriting the input which tends to be a bit more fragile.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger OK, I get that. I’ll keep using `\vec` then, it’s fine. ;)

Comment: @Archange : MarcelKrüger referred me to this answer in response to mine (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694273/a-cleaner-way-of-getting-accented-math-symbols-in-lualatex?noredirect=1#comment1723211_694273)  Marcel's solution is more sophisticated than mine, but funnily enough mine would do what you would want it to do.

Comment: Would it be possible to get this awesome piece of code added to `unicode-math` by default?