# Using unicode “combining right arrow above” to generate vector command in Plain LuaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, lua

As Marcel Krüger has shown in his answer

[Using unicode "combining right arrow above" to generate vector command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171356/using-unicode-combining-right-arrow-above-to-generate-vector-command/456225)

it is possible to use the “combining right arrow above” as the `\vec` command. This improves the readability in the source extremly. I have some documents with so much vectors.

I copied the answer and tried it. No problem. But I would like to use this solution in Plain LuaTeX, but there the letters do not get accented at all allthough I have not modified the code. What is wrong here?

MWE:

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\fourteenmath="latinmodern-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at 14.4 pt
\textfont1=\fourteenmath

\Umathcode`x="7"1`x
\Umathcode`y="7"1`y
\protected\def\vec{\Umathaccent fixed"0"1"20D7 }

$$ \vec xy $$% Works.

\mathcode"20D7="8000
\def\aftervec{\directlua{
    local nest = tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr]
    local last = nest.tail
    if not last or not last.id == 18 then
    error'I can only put accents on simple noads.'
    end
    if last.sub or last.sup then
    error'If you want accents on a superscript or subscript, please use braces.'
    end
    local acc = node.new(21, 1)
    acc.nucleus = last.nucleus
    last.nucleus = nil
    acc.accent = node.new(23)
    acc.accent.fam, acc.accent.char = 0, 0x20D7
    print(last, nest.head)
    nest.head = node.insert_after(node.remove(nest.head, last), nil, acc)
    nest.tail = acc
    node.flush_node(last)
    }}
\letcharcode"20D7=\aftervec

$$ x⃗y $$ % x does not get accented.

\bye
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Lua code has to be aware which font the accent is supposed to come from. Using the unicode-math package this isn't that important because all math families are basically the same, but in your case the `latinmodermath-regular.otf` font is "only" loaded in family `1`. The important line is

```
acc.accent.fam, acc.accent.char = 0, 0x20D7
```

This sets `fam`, the mathematical family, to `0` and `char`, the slot in the font, to `0x20D7`. You loaded the font in family 1, so you need

```
acc.accent.fam, acc.accent.char = 1, 0x20D7
```

instead.
Then you get

[image]

Comment: What a mistake... Sorry for wasting your time, but I am a beginner in `lua`.