# Use unicode COMBINING LOW LINE (U+0332) as underline

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode, lua, directlua

In the same vein as [Using unicode "combining right arrow above" to generate vector command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171356/56823), I’d like to use U+0332 “ ̲” as a “graphical” alias for `\underline`.

I don’t know Lua, so I’m not sure how to adapt this code to do this. Note that this is not considered as a math accent (not sure why though), so it’s not just about replacing the three `20D7` instances by `0332`, I’ve tried that and it does not give the expected result (bars are placed way too high). It’s really about this having the same effect as an `\underline` around the content, so that e.g. both lines in the following MWE produce the same output:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $\underline{j}$
    $j̲$
\end{document}
```

I would of course also accept a solution without Lua, it’s just that given the linked question, I thought Lua will likely be the easiest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two changes necessary to the code in my answer to the linked question to allow it to work with accents below other characters:

1. First, you don't just have to scan for `\mathaccent` codepoints (which are always above the character), but also for `\mathbotaccentwide` (the type used in `unicode-math-table.tex` for bottom accents).
2. Additionally the Lua code has to change to save the accent parameters to `bot_accent` instead of `accent` to tell LuaTeX to place them at the bottom.

This can be done with (based on the code from the previous question)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\protected\def\afteracc{\directlua{
    local nest = tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr]
    local last = nest.tail
    if not (last and last.id == 18) then
      error'I can only put accents on simple noads.'
    end
    if last.sub or last.sup then
      error'If you want accents on a superscript or subscript, please use braces.'
    end
    local acc = node.new(21, 1)
    acc.nucleus = last.nucleus
    last.nucleus = nil
    local is_bottom = token.scan_keyword'bot' and 'bot_accent' or 'accent'
    acc[is_bottom] = node.new(23)
    acc[is_bottom].fam, acc[is_bottom].char = 0, token.scan_int()
    nest.head = node.insert_after(node.remove(nest.head, last), nil, acc)
    nest.tail = acc
    node.flush_node(last)
  }}
\AtBeginDocument{
\begingroup
  \def\UnicodeMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifx#3\mathaccent
      \def\mytmpmacro{\afteracc#1 }%
      \global\letcharcode#1=\mytmpmacro
      \global\mathcode#1="8000
    \else\ifx#3\mathbotaccentwide
      \def\mytmpmacro{\afteracc bot#1 }%
      \global\letcharcode#1=\mytmpmacro
      \global\mathcode#1="8000
    \fi\fi
  }
  \input{unicode-math-table}
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
$x̃ŷz̄x⃗y̲z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The underline here will not be the same as the one created by `\underline` but it will be the one created by `\mathunderbar` (`unicode-math`'s name for U+0332).

If you don't want your fonts version of U+0332 but instead want TeX to draw a line as for `\underline`, you can instead set the mathclass to `under`(10) (which correspond to underline):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\protected\def\afterunder{\directlua{
    local last = tex.nest.top.tail
    if not (last and last.id == 18) then
      tex.error'I can only put underlines under simple noads.'
    elseif last.sub or last.sup then
      tex.error'If you want underlines on a superscript or subscript, please use braces.'
    else
      last.subtype = 10
    end
  }}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \letcharcode"0332=\afterunder
  \mathcode"0332="8000
}

\begin{document}
$\underline{y}+y̲$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code, which indeed nicely expand your answer in the previous question. But indeed it does not exactly match what I want, because it results in a different looking than `\underline`. So, supposing I accept breaking this “expanded unicode-math” behaviour for `\mathunderbar`, is there a way to make it result in `\underline`?

Comment: @Archange Edited to add a `\underline` version.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :) I’ve also added a similar question to the answer about `vec`, if you could have a look. ;)